# Retrieving data from Appery.io database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, rest

I am building an mobile application using Appery.io

Intend to create a functionality where users can respond (+ or -) to others profile which is briefly viewed. A user should only be able to respond Once. Hence it is unnecessary to show that profile again when the user visit Profiles Page

--- **PAGES** --- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Reponses Page - List all reponses the Loggedin User has RESPONDED

Profiles Page - Views profiles Loggedin User has NOT RESPONDED [One Profile at a time] & Ability to respond (+ or -)

--- **DATABASE** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

User Information are stored in users[_id, username, password, mobile_number]
All responses are stored in a collection responses[_id, user_id, recipient_id, state]

--- **PROBLEM** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Trying to skip the profiles that the Loggedin User has already reponded to in Responses Page

After hours of research I am unable to find a solution as to what is causing the problem.

In Appery.io it is required to use SERVER CODE to do this. Getting a few errors, my server code is as follows:

```
var DB_id = request.get("DB_id"); //Get the "DB_id" parameter from the request and store it 
var userName = request.get("userName"); //Store the user name
var token = request.get("token"); // Get token from localstorage varbiable UserSessiontoken
var usercollection = "Users"; 
var Reponsescollection = "Responses";
try {
  profiles = {};

 //gets a collection list and save it to the response
 //var profiles = Profile.getCollectionList("SELECT * FROM 'users' NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM Responses WHERE `user_id`=  + 'userId' +)");

 //Make the query and save it to the profiles object
 profiles.query = profile.query(DB_id, usercollection, "parameters": {"where": {"user_id": {"$userId" : {"$nin": {"Reponsescollection"}}}}, token);

 profiles.profilesList = Profile.getCollectionList(profiles); //Call the getCollectionList and save its response to the profiles

  response.success(profiles); //Pass the result object to the response.
  response.success("This actually Works!!!");
} catch (e) {
  response.success("message: " + e.message + " ncode: " + e.code); //If something goes wrong error message will appear
}
```

--- **ERROR MSGS** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ON TEST TAB -----
Error code SCSE014: Script execution failed

A step by step solution specific to this problem would be **much appreciated**.

Comment: Have you asked in the Appery forum? The staff is usually very responsive. https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio

Comment: Yes I have, but only got links to documentations. Apparently didn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do, but why not get the collection directly on the client side? Same query as a REST service.

Comment: It is required to query both collections [Users (Pre defined) & Responses] in order to get a certain set of results. 

In this case I want to view all users in Collection[Users] that does not exist in Collection[Responses] based on the 'id'